# How to stop a custom \section macro from adding whitespace to the beginning of a paragraph?

Tags: spacing, macros, sectioning, plain-tex

I lifted a `\section` macro from the TeXbook.

```
\outer\def\section#1{\medbreak\noindent{\bf#1}\smallskip\par\nobreak\noindent}
```

When I use this macro like this:

```
\section{\TeX nical documenation}
Blah blah blah \TeX\ blah blah\dots
```

An unwanted blank is added before the beginning of the paragraph. I suspect this comes from the newline after the `\section` invocation and before the paragraph. Knuth circumvents this problem by not placing his `\exercise` macro in a line on its own:

```
\exercise After you have mastered the material in this book,
what will you be: A \TeX pert, or a \TeX nician?
\answer A \TeX nician (underpaid); sometimes also called
a \TeX acker.
```

I was able to fix this problem by having `\section` gobble up whitespace after its argument:

```
\outer\def\section#1 {\medbreak\noindent{\bf#1}\smallskip\par\nobreak\noindent}
```

Is this a good solution to the problem? If no, what is the recommended solution for this kind of situation?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand the question, but the `\smallskip` looks suspicious to me; that's a vertical mode command, and you are still in horizontal mode when you issue it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton If I understood TeX correctly, `\smallskip` automatically leaves horizontal mode. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @FUZxxl it does, but that means the following `\par` does nothing (and the `\nobreak` is too late, better `\par\nobreak\smallskip`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for this remark. This kind of stuff is important!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting `\ignorespaces`: with `\noindent` you start a paragraph, so spaces are not ignored, unless you tell TeX to.

```
\outer\def\section#1{%
  \medbreak
  \noindent{\bf#1}\par
  \nobreak\smallskip
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}
```

Note that `\nobreak` should go *before* `\smallskip` because TeX is allowed to break at glue, if not preceded by discardable items (like a penalty).

Note that in Knuth's code, writing

```
\exercise After you have mastered the material in this book,
what will you be: A \TeX pert, or a \TeX nician?
```

or

```
\exercise
After you have mastered the material in this book,
what will you be: A \TeX pert, or a \TeX nician?
```

is exactly the same, because spaces following control sequences *in input* are thrown away to begin with. In your case the space after the `}` is not ignored (it comes from the end-of-line, but it's the same thing).

Answer (score 3):

Using `\noindent` means that your heading command has already started the first paragraph. If you know that sections always start with text this is OK (and in the spirit of plain tex commands that aim to be simple and easily customised rather than generally robust).

The disadvantage is if you want to start any section with any vertical display material such as a list. If you start a paragraph after the heading then the paragraph started by `\noindent` will end and you will get a spurious "white" para just consisting of a horizontal box filled with `\parfillskip`.

What latex does here is to set `\everypar` to remove the indentation box with `\setbox0=\lastbox` that way you can be in vertical mode after the heading (and special environments like lists can detect the special `\everypar` and do something appropriate.

Being in vertical mode will naturally mean that spaces are ignored and avoid the
problem noted in the question with white space at the start of the paragraph.

Note that in your existing macro, `\smallskip` starts vertical mode, but that means the following `\par` does nothing (and the `\nobreak` is too late, better

```
 \par\nobreak\smallskip
```